# find file path from one line and insert into the next line with Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, filepath

I'm writing a batch file to copy a file across network computers and change the attributes to remove the archive bit.  The computer name and file path is different depending on the computer.  I need to pull the path from one line and insert it into another line as below.

```
Net use k: /delete /y

Net use k: \\computername\path\subfolder

Xcopy c:\path\subfolder\File.txt /s /y /k k:\path001002\

attrib -a k:\XF001002\File.txt
```

Where path001002 on the first line needs to be inserted in the second line.  I've got over 200 entries and don't want to have to manually edit every 4th line.

Another option is maybe to find a batch file switch that will remove the archive bit on the destination file on the Xcopy command.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but including newlines in a find/replace regex should enable you to do what you need to do - that or maybe modifying the batch file to use a subroutine/call another batch. Another option might be to make a text file listing the files/computers and process that with a batch file.